# Copying images from Gimp to Lotus Notes via clipboard ruined color depth

Tags: image, lotus-notes, clipboard, gimp

I have for example this image:

[image]

When I open it in web-browser and use ctrl-c ctrl-v to lotus-notes, it is copied correctly.

[image]

But, when I copy image firstly into gimp, and after that to Lotus Notes, It ruined color depth and images look fuzy. (browser ctrl-c -> ctrl-v GIMP -> ctrl-c in GIMP -> ctrl-v Lotus Notes)

[image]

Can anybody please help why this is happening, and how to fix? I need to use ctrl-c+v because of processing big amount of images. Any other method of importing images to Lotus Notes will slow my work.

Thx.

LN 8.5.3 and 7 
Gimp 2.8.2 and 2.6
Win 7 and XP

Also Windows Paint do the same,...

EDIT:

Test on rich text in another app. First image is imported from browser, second from gimp:

[image]

Comment: You using standard or basic client? Also if you use the 8.5.3 template do you get the same issue?

Comment: Revision 20110916.0921 (Release 8.5.3) Standard Configuration. Basic mail template do the same. Copying image to any richtext in any application do the same,...

Comment: Cheers. Just to check some other points. If you use other methods (although slower) do you see the same degradation? Or if you render in a browser do you see the same issue?

Comment: Also test this. Do "Edit->Paste As". It should show the types of rendering of the image when pasting. Do you get the same results on each type? Or only one option?

Comment: I can paste image by script - Save image in Gimp and import image file into LN. It save image to RichText without degradation. But image is saved as file, not as data in RichText (Maybe that's why images from web browser are also rendered right). As another paste methods (Paste AS) I can chose Bitmap or Device Independent Bitmap, both with same degradation as classic Paste. Thanks for your help and time on this issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and reproduced (R853FP5/R901). I checked for existing issues and unfortunately it is a known issue with the Windows client.

It has been reported to development as SPR [MLEY8TPD2Y](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO68984). So if you can open a PMR (support call), you can add your customer report to the SPR.

There is no work around, although the Mac Version of Notes correctly pastes the image.